# How to center a grouped UITableView vertically on iphone screen?

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard

I have tried adding a headerView to the tableview and setting its height as follows
(suppose we have 3 cells here)

```
(self.tableView.bounds.size.height - self.tableView.rowHeight*3 - self.tableView.sectionHeaderHeight - self.tableView.sectionFooterHeight)/2;
```

It appears to be centered but the alignment is actually 5 pixel off.

I want to use storyboards but without container views as they only work for ios 6. I want it to work on ios 5.1 at least